# show that for any irrational $\alpha $ the limit $\lim _{n \to\infty} \sin n \alpha \pi $ does not exist ..

Tags: real-analysis

1)show that for any irrational $\alpha $   the limit  $\lim _{n\to\infty} \sin n \alpha \pi $  does not exist ..

2) show that for any rational $\alpha $  the limit  $\lim _{n \rightarrow  \infty} \sin (n! \alpha \pi) $   exist ?

My attempts : For 1)  I'm very  confused ?????

For  2) let $ \alpha =\frac {p}{q}$ with $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ and  $q \in \mathbb{N}$ . For $n > q  $  the number  $n ! \alpha \pi$ is  a multiple of $\pi $, which means  that the terms  of  the  sequence , beginning  with some Value  $ n_{0} $of the index n, are all equal to $0$

as  in 1) I'm very confused. How  can  I approach this kind of problems ??

Pliz help me

Thanks un

Comment: If you can get approximations $|\alpha-p/n|<1/n^2$ for many $n$'s, then $|n\alpha\pi-p\pi|<\pi/n$, which means that $\sin(n\alpha \pi)$ is arbitrarily close to $\sin(p\pi)=0$. Likewise, if you can get approximations $|2\alpha-p/n|<1/n^2$ for many $n$'s with $p$ odd, then $|n\alpha\pi-p\pi/2|<\pi/(2n)$. This means that $\sin(n\alpha\pi)$ is very close to $\sin(p\pi/2)=\pm1$. Now look at [some of what is known about rational approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_approximation#Upper_bounds_for_Diophantine_approximations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1).

For real $x$ let $[x]$ be the largest integer not exceeding $x.$ Let $\{x\}$ denote the non-negative fractional part of $x.$ That is, $\{x\}=x-[x].$

It is an old result, provable by elementary means, that if $\alpha$ is an irrational  real then $\{\{n\alpha\}: n\in \Bbb N\}$ is dense in $[0,1].$

So there are infinitely many $n\in \Bbb N$ such that $1/3<\{n\alpha\}<1/2$ and  there are infinitely many $n\in \Bbb N $ such that $ 0<\{n\alpha\}<1/6.$

So there are infinitely many $n\in \Bbb N$ such that $|\sin n\alpha \pi|>\sqrt 3\;/2> 0.866$ and there are  infinitely many $n\in \Bbb N$ such that $|\sin n\alpha  \pi|<0.5.$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $\alpha$ be irrational. Prove that
$$
\mathbb N \cdot \alpha \mod 2
$$
is dense in $[0,2]$. Hence
$$
(\mathbb N \cdot \alpha \cdot \pi) \mod 2 \pi
$$
is dense in $[0,2\pi]$. By the continuity of $\sin$ the result follows.